Breaking a retro video game hash
The video game Skeleton Warriors for Sega Saturn uses a custom hash function to check for cheat codes entered at the pause screen. The function is equivalent to the Python code below.
After computation, the hash results are compared to a list of values associated with cheat codes. For example:

Entering X, X, X, X, Y, Y, Y, Y on the controller produces the hash 00001555dddc7332, which is associated with a "show coordinates" effect.
Entering C, Right, A, Z, Y, B, A, Left, Left produces the hash 000dd8d3a498d510, which is associated with the "bouncing" effect.

These effects have been for decades, but there's one effect that's gone unreported. Its hash is 8f9d0b0ccffa2be3. I know what it does — it makes the game show hit boxes — but not what the button sequence is.
The hash doesn't look at all secure, but I've not been able to reverse this particular value yet. I tried brute force enumeration of all the input sequences up to 9 characters, but no luck there.
The codes tend to spell out words with the restricted alphabet (notice CRAZYBALL above — another is LUCCY LUCCY), and I was able to recover all of the already-known ones with a dictionary attack, but again, not the unknown one.
Is there a way to exploit the weakness of the algorithm to recover the plaintext? Is this algorithm an implementation of something that's already been studied?
I suspect that the target is 18 characters long, because the game converts the button presses to ASCII and stores them in memory as you enter them. There are 19 bytes allocated to that buffer.
letter_map = {
    "l": 1, "r": 2, "u": 3, "d": 4,
    "a": 5, "b": 6, "c": 7, "x": 8,
    "y": 9, "z": 10,
}


def process_sequence(code_buttons):
    buffer_01 = 0
    buffer_02 = 0

    for button in code_buttons:
        index = letter_map[button]
        for __ in range(4):
            if (index & 1) != 0:
                buffer_02 = buffer_02 ^ 0xA001
            x = ((buffer_01 & 0x80000000) == 0) ^ 1
            y = ((buffer_02 & 0x80000000) == 0) ^ 1
            buffer_01 = (buffer_01 * 2 + y) & 0xFFFFFFFF
            buffer_02 = (buffer_02 * 2 + x) & 0xFFFFFFFF
            index = index >> 1

    return (buffer_01 << 32) | buffer_02


Edit: The comments give answers that satisfy my question, but not the game! It also computes a third buffer_ value - I didn't think it mattered, because it doesn't for the other codes. It must apply to this one because of its length.
The third hash component is 08B25A87.
def cheat_code_helper(index_, cheat_buffer_03):
    iVar1 = (cheat_buffer_03 & 0xFFFF) * (index_ & 0xFFFF)
    if (((index_ >> 0x10) << 0x10) | (cheat_buffer_03 >> 0x10)) == 0:
        return iVar1

    return (
        iVar1
        + (
            (index_ & 0xFFFF) * (cheat_buffer_03 >> 0x10)
            + (cheat_buffer_03 & 0xFFFF) * (index_ >> 0x10)
        )
        * 0x10000
    )


def process_sequence(code_buttons):
    buffer_01 = 0
    buffer_02 = 0
    buffer_03 = 1

    for button in code_buttons:
        index = letter_map[button]
        buffer_03 = (cheat_code_helper(index + 1, buffer_03) + buffer_02) & 0xFFFFFFFF
        for __ in range(4):
            if (index & 1) != 0:
                buffer_02 = buffer_02 ^ 0xA001
            x = ((buffer_01 & 0x80000000) == 0) ^ 1
            y = ((buffer_02 & 0x80000000) == 0) ^ 1
            buffer_01 = (buffer_01 * 2 + y) & 0xFFFFFFFF
            buffer_02 = (buffer_02 * 2 + x) & 0xFFFFFFFF
            index = index >> 1

    return (buffer_01, buffer_02, buffer_03)

Another edit: The ASCII buffer is 19 bytes rather than 18.
And another: I fixed the Python implementation of the helper. The initial condition for buffer_03 is 1, not 0!

Funny riddle. The answer is ybulldazzlzduuru, and can be obtained by a simple division in the ring $\mathbb{F}_2[x]/(x^{64}+1)$. I'll give a more detailed answer later if needed.

@MehdiTibouchi My code returned dybulldazzlzduurc. I'm not sure why it missed your answer as both are valid as 0xA001 divides the difference.

You're both right, but I left out a piece because I didn't think it mattered! There's a third component to the hash (32 bit word #1, 32 bit word #2). I'll update the question with the details. It must be the tiebreaker
Is there a way to enumerate all matches?

Yes, one can easily enumerate all the matches of a given length. The one I gave is the only solution in 16 characters, but there are 8 solutions in 17 characters (one of which is mentioned by @DanielS), and 64 solutions in 18 characters, and more if the input can be longer still. What is the condition on the 3rd buffer?

I've updated the question with the additional condition. I'm sure that the limit is less than 20 characters from the game assembly!

I misinterpreted some of the machine code earlier; the initial condition for the third hash value is 1 and not 0 - the Python implementation now matches.
Adding dazzlz to my dictionary did produce some candidates that match the first two components, but I haven't found the true answer yet. Close!

Aha! The answer is rubybulldazzlzdulla. The partial answers here were enough to augment the dictionary such that it found the correct hashes. Thank you for this excellent assistance!
